# Scraping of website through Puppeteer returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I was trying to scrape the Myntra website. The link is [here](https://www.myntra.com/jeans/pepe-jeans/pepe-jeans-women-black-lara-lola-regular-fit-mid-rise-clean-look-stretchable-jeans/11280352/buy)

I used Puppeteer and Node JS to scrape it. It was working fine and currently I get an error

```
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:55
```

The function returns an empty object. I have attached my code below.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.myntra.com/jeans/only/only-women-black-skinny-fit-mid-rise-low-distress-stretchable-cropped-jeans/10973332/buy');
    const body = await page.evaluate( () => {
     return document.querySelector('.pdp-price') ;
    });
    console.log(body);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this site is blocking requests for which `HeadlessChrome` is specified in the `user-agent`, so I changed the `user-agent` and now everything works as you need. Try this code:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'
    });
    await page.goto('https://www.myntra.com/jeans/only/only-women-black-skinny-fit-mid-rise-low-distress-stretchable-cropped-jeans/10973332/buy');
    const body = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelector('.pdp-price').textContent;
    });
    console.log(body);
    await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```

Comment: I'm very glad that my decision helped you. Regarding thanks in the comments - you need to read [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).
Thanks you.

Comment: 'Please contact your administrator' , I tried but getting this issue

Answer (score 0):

Something is trying to call `.textContent` on something that's `null`. I don't see it in your example, but this is what would happen if code like `querySelector('.pdp-price')` doesn't find anything - maybe because the page hasn't fully loaded yet or the selector doesn't match anything.

You can pass [other options to `page.goto`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.12.2&show=api-pagegotourl-options) to make it wait for longer, which could let things load.